# How to show textbox one by one on button click

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have created 3 textboxes like,

If i click a button, i need to display txtChoice_1 and if I click that button 2nd time it will display

the txtChoice_2 like wise, I need to display these textboxes one by one for every click.

Any idea?

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: do you want to make this using jquery/Javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your requirements are, but here is a JQuery solution:

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/obyns05e/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" class="tb">
    <input type="text" class="tb">
    <input type="text" class="tb">
</div>
<input type="submit" class="clickMe">
```

**JQuery**

```
//Hide all of the text boxes on document ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($('.tb'), function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});

$('.clickMe').click(function() {
  //Find the first hidden text box
  var tb = $('.inputs').find('input:hidden').first();
  //Length will always be one if there is at least one hidden text box.
  if ($(tb).length == 1) { 
    $(tb).show();
  } 
  else {
    alert('No more');
    //You can extend this by hiding the text boxes once there are no more to show (or whatever else you want).
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could very easily build a function in JS. If you gave your button an onclick event to a function 'showTextBoxes', you could one by one should the textboxes. Something like this, which just demonstrates how to show one box. You could quite easily add a small loop and counter to check how many time someone has clicked, but that challenge I leave to you:)

```js
$('.txtChoice_1').hide();
$('.txtChoice_2').hide();
$('.txtChoice_3').hide(); //You could further optimize this too

showTextBoxes = function () {
  //TODO: Add global variable so you can track the number of amounts clicked
  $('.txtChoice_1').show();
};
```